# How to use regex with optional characters in python?

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a string

```
"3434.35353"
```

and another string

```
"3593"
```

How do I make a single regular expression that is able to match both without me having to set the pattern to something else if the other fails? I know `\d+` would match the `3593`, but it would not do anything for the `3434.35353`, but (`\d+\.\d+`) would only match the one with the decimal and return no matches found for the `3593`.

I expect `m.group(1)` to return:

```
"3434.35353"
```

or

```
"3593"
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can put a `?` after a group of characters to make it optional.

You want a dot followed by any number of digits `\.\d+`, grouped together `(\.\d+)`, optionally `(\.\d+)?`. Stick that in your pattern:

```
import re
print re.match("(\d+(\.\d+)?)", "3434.35353").group(1)
```

```
3434.35353
```

```
print re.match("(\d+(\.\d+)?)", "3434").group(1)
```

```
3434
```

Answer (score 5):

This regex should work:

```
\d+(\.\d+)?
```

It matches one ore more digits (`\d+`) optionally followed by a dot and one or more digits (`(\.\d+)?`).

Answer (score 3):

use `(?:<characters>|)`. replace `<characters>` with the string to make optional. I tested in python shell and got the following result:

````
>>> s = re.compile('python(?:3|)')
>>> s
re.compile('python(?:3|)')
>>> re.match(s, 'python')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='python'>
>>> re.match(s, 'python3')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='python3'>```
````

Comment: I prefer this method when I don't desire to use the nested capture groups. For example, if would like to capture all of the digits & '.' inside parentheses for '(1)' or '(333.333.333)'. I would like the entire string (and more things after). I can treat them both as one group for later iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "one or zero" quantifier, `?`. Your regex becomes: `(\d+(\.\d+)?)`.

See Chapter 8 of the [TextWrangler manual](http://pine.barebones.com/manual/TextWrangler_User_Manual.pdf) for more details about the different quantifiers available, and how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on the [Python RegEx](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) library. The link answers your question and explains why.

However, to match a digit followed by more digits with an optional decimal, you can use

```
re.compile("(\d+(\.\d+)?)")
```

In this example, the ? after the `.\d+` capture group specifies that this portion is optional.

[Example](http://regexr.com?30fbt)